# Can smart publish be configured to clear HTML Cache for a page when it's child page has been published?

Tags: publishing, caching

Smart Publish appears to clean out HTMLCache selectively, essentially only for the items that have been published rather than fully clearing out the HTML cache.

I have several pages whose content is dependent on it's child items and doesnt get updated when the child item is smart published.

Is there a way to indicate to sitecore that these are "related" content and to kick out the parent page's HTML from the cache when the child item is published?

Or would I need to create a custom cache clearing strategy for that page's renderings?

Comment: The `HtmlCacheClearer` always clears the full html cache. I would say you have another cache that is holding on to something and isn't getting cleared.

Comment: Even for smart publishing? Unless I've missed something when I've published (using 9.2) it looks like it kicks out only the published item's html.

Comment: Unless something has changed in 9.2, HtmlCache is always fully cleared for any type of publish.

Comment: Maybe it's local cache related.. I'll take a look at the browser cache if that's not preventing the content update.